# select a nested attributes in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is an online shop

I create Product with nested sizes_attributes

A customer can buy a product and he has to select his size

**products_controller.rb**

```
  def params_product
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, 
:category_id, :color, sizes_attributes: [:id, :size_name, :quantity, :_destroy])
   end
```

**products/show.html.erb**

So the customer can select the wanted quantity and his size

```
   <%= form_tag order_items_path do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
    <%= number_field_tag :quantity, 1 %> 
    <%= collection_select :size, :id, @product.sizes, :id, :size_name, prompt: "Votre taille" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add to Cart" %>
   <% end %>
```

**shopping_cart.rb**

```
  def initialize(token:)
    @token = token
  end

  def order
   @order ||= Order.find_or_create_by(token: @token, status: 0) do |order|
    order.sub_total = 0
   end
 end

 def add_item(product_id:, quantity: 1, user_id:, size_id:)
   @product = Product.find(product_id)
   @size = Size.find_by(id: size_id)
   #binding.pry

   user = User.find(user_id)
   order.user_id = user.id

   order_item = order.items.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: product_id)
   order_item.price = @product.price
   order_item.quantity = quantity
   order_item.size_id = @size.id


   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     order_item.save
   end
 end
```

**order_items_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    current_cart.add_item(
     product_id: params[:product_id],
     quantity: params[:quantity],
     user_id: params[:user_id],
     size_id: params[:size_id]
   )
  end
```

#### So the problem is:

- The available sizes on a product can be ["S","M","L","XL"]
- My user has selected "L"
- The selected size is not saved

It records "S"...

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the web server console messages for this transaction? There should be one where it shows the params being submitted, that will help ensure that what you expect to be sent by the form is being sent and accepted by the controller. Also right click on your form and inspect the size element and make sure the ERB is producing the HTML you are expecting. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that something is wrong with how your params are being submitted by the form, most likely a lack of nesting in the params being submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection_select` generates a select field with name="size[id]", and you get `{size: {id 1}}` instead of `{size_id: 1}` in controller params. What you need is select_tag helper here:

```
<%= select_tag :size_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@product.sizes, :id, :size_name), prompt: "Votre taille" %>
```